# Volumetric Fog using Unity's shader graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, volume

I was wondering if it was possible to create a volumetric fog using unity shader graph.

I'm struggling to achieved this shader.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade HDRP to take advantage of built-in [Volumetic Fog](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-volumetric-fog-19) ? Have you tried applying a [Depth Node](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Scene-Depth-Node.html) and linking it with a camera to simulate fog limited to an object or plane?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it requires deep knowledge of shader writing. Why not use the built-in [Volumetric Fog](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@4.8/manual/Volumetric-Fog.html)? Unity has its own implementation, and installation guide.

Comment: I used the Universal Render Pipeline not the HDRP